# Using winreg to decrypt reg binaries

Tags: python, encryption, winreg

I am trying to decode a reg binary from the registry. Not necessarily decode. I just want to get the real value ( Not the binary or hex value) of reg binary in  the registry.

I opened the registry and navigated to
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`
[Click for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU1UI.jpg)

To get the productID key, I copied the value

**a4 00 00 00 03...**
to my python shell.

Since this is a hex string I used
`hex('0xa4 00 00 00 03')`
to get the values. This does not seem correct even to me. I have compared my answer with that given by other software and mine is different. So I am sure that I am not doing it the right way.

Is there a way to do this in winreg. That is decrypt the value of a reg binary. Or is there something else I should do.
Thanks in advance

Comment: [`bytes.fromhex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex), [`binascii.unhexlify()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify)

Comment: As the type `REG-BINARY` should make clear, the binary value *is* "the real value". `regedit` displays it as hex with spaces between the bytes because a lot of binary values can't be meaningfully displayed on a screen, such as 0x08, which is in ascii is backspace.

Comment: For a while, I thought my question was ambiguous. Thanks for answering. But I really didn't get the value I was expecting. I am new to python in case I forgot to mention it. I was getting something like **b'\xa4\x00'** when I am expecting a sequence of 25 digit numbers. How can I convert it to a code like **234XJ-24...** which third party softwares interprete it as.